# Angle between 3 points math explain

Tags: javascript, c++, math, vector

I have converted a c++ code into javascript which calculates angle between 3 points. Though it is working properly I do not understand math behind it.

```js
    function angle(a, b, c) {
        var ab = { x: b.x - a.x, y: b.y - a.y };
        var cb = { x: b.x - c.x, y: b.y - c.y };

        var dot = (ab.x * cb.x + ab.y * cb.y); // dot product
        var cross = (ab.x * cb.y - ab.y * cb.x); // cross product

        var alpha = -Math.atan2(cross, dot);
        if (alpha < 0) alpha += 2 * Math.PI;
        return alpha;
    }
```

What is the use of dot and cross product here? How does atan2 use cross and dot products to calculate angle?

Comment: Unit vectors enable two convenient identities: the dot product of two unit vectors yields the cosine (which may be positive or negative) of the angle between the two unit vectors. The magnitude of the cross product of the two unit vectors yields the sine (which will always be positive).

Comment: what do you mean with "angle between 3 points" ? Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211212/how-to-calculate-an-angle-from-three-points

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361412/finding-the-angle-between-three-points

Comment: as the question isnt really about code, it would be better at https://math.stackexchange.com/ It is not c++ **and** javascript at the same time anyhow

Comment: This is related to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486172/angle-between-3-points

Comment: That's not a cross product – the cross product is a vector and is only defined in three-dimensional space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ab = { x: b.x - a.x, y: b.y - a.y };
var cb = { x: b.x - c.x, y: b.y - c.y };
```

these points represent the lines AB and BC. Now dot product of 2 lines is

```
dot = |AB|.|BC|.cos(theta)
cross = |AB|.|BC|.sin(theta)
```

their division would get

```
cross/dot = tan(theta)
```

so

```
theta = atan(cross, dot)
```

we know the value of dot and cross from

```
dot = (ab.x * cb.x + ab.y * cb.y);
cross = (ab.x * cb.y - ab.y * cb.x);
```

hence we can find the angle using the above information

Comment: The `theta = atan(cross, dot)` is actually `atan(cross/dot)`.   In programming languages (or their libraries) like C and JavaScript, that is expressed in alternate form as `atan2(cross, dot)` which ensures an angle in the correct quadrant (and avoids problems of division by zero if `dot` is zero), to give a result between `-PI` and `PI`