# Angle in triangle by coordinates C

Tags: c

i have to find angle ∠BAC in triangle ABC with given coordinates. I'm trying to find cos, then use function acos(cos) and get degrees(not radian) anwser.
The input is Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy coordinates

```
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int n;
    int ax,ay,bx,by,cx,cy;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i ++){
        scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",&ax,&ay,&bx,&by,&cx,&cy);
        double cosab = (ax*bx+ay*by)/ (sqrt(ax*ax+ay*ay)* sqrt(bx*bx+by*by));
        cosab =180* acos(cosab)/M_PI;
        printf("cosab is %0.20g\n",cosab);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With input

```
8
2 1 2 3 5 5
2 1 4 3 2 3
3 1 3 5 2 3
0 0 1 0 10 0
0 0 1 0 -10 1
7 4 3 3 3 3
0 0 1 0 1 1e-5
0 0 1 0 1e-5 1
```

I get

```
cosab is 29.744881296942211
cosab is 10.304846468766044
cosab is 40.601294645004479
cosab is -1.#IND
cosab is -1.#IND
cosab is 15.255118703057764
cosab is -1.#IND
cosab is -1.#IND
```

But the anwser should be

```
36.869897645844019962
45
26.565051177077990019
0
174.28940686250035697
0
0.00057295779511172474814
89.999427042204885652
```

What is "-1.#IND" and what's wrong with my code?

Comment: `1e-5` can't be loaded into an integer meaningfully for one thing. Consider making your coordinates `double`s

Comment: Note that input `7 4 3 3 3 3` isn't a valid triangle.

Comment: IND stands for indeterminate

Comment: Shouldn't the [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486172/angle-between-3-points) involve the *difference* between pairs of x-coordinates and y-coordinates?

Comment: There are a bunch of questions here, whether you realize it or not. I recommend making a [MCVE]: get rid of the input red herrings, hard-code 6 values for coordinates, and make sure you can implement the law of cosines correctly. Then, if you have problems with the other frills in the problem, ask separate questions for those items.

Comment: Aside: the second assignment of `cosab = ...` should arguably be `double angle = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the input coordinates are floating point, so let us read them into `double`s:

```
        double ax,ay,bx,by,cx,cy;
        /* Read coordinates of A, B, and C. */
        scanf("%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf",&ax,&ay,&bx,&by,&cx,&cy);
```

∠BAC is the angle between lines AB and AC.  Let us consider those as vectors **AB** and **AC** represented by their *x* and *y* components:

```
        /* Convert to vectors AB and AC (as x and y components). */
        double abx = bx - ax;   /* x component of vector AB */
        double aby = by - ay;   /* y component of vector AB */
        double acx = cx - ax;   /* x component of vector AC */
        double acy = cy - ay;   /* y component of vector AC */
```

Now there is a nice formula using ATAN2 on the vector components to get the angle of rotation from one 2D vector to another<sup>1</sup>:

```
        /*
         * Get angle of rotation from vector AB to vector AC
         * in the range [-M_PI, +M_PI].
         */
        double rot_ab_ac = atan2(acy*abx - acx*aby, acx*abx + acy*aby);
```

We want the absolute angle, not a signed angle:

```
        /* Convert to absolute angle BAC. */
        double bac = fabs(rot_ab_ac);
```

Finally, we want the angle in degrees, not radians:

```
        /* Convert to degrees. */
        double bac_deg = bac * 180.0 / M_PI;
```

Note: `M_PI` is not defined in the C standard, but can be easily defined by a macro if necessary:

```
#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [Angle Between Two Vectors 2D Formula](https://wumbo.net/formula/angle-between-two-vectors-2d/)

Comment: @chux Thanks. Actually OP says ∠BAC in the question, and it seems to match, e.g. A(2,1), B(4,3), C(2,3) has ∠A=45°, ∠B=45°, ∠C=90°. (∠BAC is ∠A)

Comment: `atan2()` is the better way to go.  `acos()` has computational edge concerns.

Answer (score 1):

**Input is not only integers**

`1e-5` is like `0.00001`.  Read that into a `double`.

```
// int ax,ay,bx,by,cx,cy;
double ax,ay,bx,by,cx,cy;
...
    //scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",&ax,&ay,&bx,&by,&cx,&cy);
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf",&ax,&ay,&bx,&by,&cx,&cy);
```

**Be careful with `acos()`**

The `|x|` in `acos(x)` may be just a tad larger than 1.0 due to computationally issues.  Best to check

```
// add
if (cosab > 1.0) cosab = 1.0;
else if (cosab < -1.0) cosab = -1.0;

cosab = 180 * acos(cosab) / M_PI;
```

**Perhaps better precision**

```
// sqrt(ax*ax+ay*ay)
hypot(ax, ay)
```

**Other issues may exist too**

Worth reviewing if proper formula is used: [Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)